# VLookups returning #N/As except when pressing Enter on cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm inputting a VBA formula which returns #N/A values for every cell, except when I select a cell and press enter - when I do this, that particular lookup is changed to the correct value. For example, `Application.Vlookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A2"), ThisWorkbook.Sheet2.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)` returns #N/A but after I select A2 and hit enter, the formula fixes and I see the correct value.

In the below example, you'll see that Susie, Cormac & Michael have been selected and entered whereas the rest of them I have not touched:

[image: Vlookup test values]

I've filtered the result set to everything except #N/A which gives you just Susie, Cormac & Michael - note the results for the rest of the names is #N/A.

[image: Vlookup test results]

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Looking at the alignment of the cells, i think they are differing number formats maybe?  I'm not sure i fully understand the issue.

Comment: It looks like your ID's are numbers that are saved as text (that is why they are aligned left, text is always aligned left by defaut). If you go into the cell and press enter Excel realizes that you input a number and changes the fromat from text to numeric automatically (that is why they change their alignment to right, numbers are always aligned right by default). • Make sure you correct that issue by converting all numbers saved as text into real numbers (if you google for that you will find examples).

Comment: I dont think i am getting it right, but in the first picture Derek, Rachel etc. do have numbers in front of them and not #N/A, what am i missing?

Comment: If @Pᴇʜ is right, i think .NumberFomat = "0.00" would solve this. It changes the formating of the cell to number .NumberFomat = "@" would be if you want to format it as text.

Comment: I tried converting to numbers using the code provided above but to no avail. Just to confirm, columns are now in number format but still seeing #N/A's in the results. When I double click the value in 'Connection id', it aligns to the right and the #N/A for that result changes to the correct value. The format of the cell does not change besides this.

Comment: @Danny this is formatting issue. If you use this code on a cell that you have not pressed enter on then it should work because I force it to long. `Application.Vlookup(clng(ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A2")), ThisWorkbook.Sheet2.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)`. Because Excel is so picky in these things i generally create two vlookups, on with just lookup and one with long. Then you need to look at error code on the returned value which variable to use.